# database joomla(jos-Warning: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Duplicate entry ')

Tags: php, database, joomla, duplicates

i have problem with database joomla...

my problem showing when i delete my old site(joomla 2.5) and its having many articles and install new joomla (joomla 3.3.6) but the URL of old site get problem of **jos-Warning: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Duplicate entry '**...

**and i have 404 error page but not work with this problem**

please help me solve this problem

**and i not having any background about database**

and this full page of error:

```
jos-Warning: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Duplicate entry 'http://my-site.com/index.php/en/using-joomla-2/ext' for key 'idx_link_old' SQL=INSERT INTO `olrky_redirect_links` (`old_url`,`new_url`,`referer`,`comment`,`hits`,`published`,`created_date`) VALUES ('http://my-site.com/index.php/en/using-joomla-2/extensions-2/components-2/content-component-2/article-categories-2/169-5th-en/656-synthesis-and-study-the-biological-activity-of-some-new-bis-maleimide-derivatives-containing-1-3-4-oxadiazole-ring-2.html', '' ,'https://www.google.iq/', '',1,0, '2014-12-15 07:48:36')' in /home/*******/public_html/libraries/joomla/database/driver/mysqli.php:606 Stack trace: #0 /home/*******/public_html/plugins/system/redirect/redirect.php(114): JDatabaseDriverMysqli->execute() #1 [internal function]: PlgSystemRedirect::handleError(Object(JException)) #2 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(754): call_user_func(Array, Object(JException)) #3 [internal function]: JError::handleCallback(Object(JException), Array) #4 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(217): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(179): JError::throwError(Object(JException)) #6 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(253): JError::raise(1, 404, '\xD9\x84\xD9\x85 \xD9\x8A\xD8\xAA\xD9\x85 \xD8\xA7\xD9...', NULL, true) #7 /home/*******/public_html/components/com_content/models/article.php(162): JError::raiseError(404, '\xD9\x84\xD9\x85 \xD9\x8A\xD8\xAA\xD9\x85 \xD8\xA7\xD9...') #8 /home/*******/public_html/plugins/system/helix/core/classes/joomla30/viewlegacy.php(394): ContentModelArticle->getItem() #9 /home/*******/public_html/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php(44): JViewLegacy->get('Item') #10 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(693): ContentViewArticle->display() #11 /home/*******/public_html/components/com_content/controller.php(79): JControllerLegacy->display(true, Array) #12 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(730): ContentController->display() #13 /home/*******/public_html/components/com_content/content.php(16): JControllerLegacy->execute(NULL) #14 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(352): require_once('/home/*******/...') #15 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(332): JComponentHelper::executeComponent('/home/*******/...') #16 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_content') #17 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(237): JApplicationSite->dispatch() #18 /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(251): JApplicationSite->doExecute() #19 /home/*******/public_html/index.php(40): JApplicationCms->execute() #20 {main}JApplicationCms -> execute() @ /home/******/public_html/index.php:40
JApplicationSite -> doExecute() @ /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php:251
JApplicationSite -> dispatch() @ /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php:237
JComponentHelper :: renderComponent() @ /home/********/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php:191
JComponentHelper :: executeComponent() @ /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:332
require_once() @ /home/*******/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php:352
JControllerLegacy -> execute() @ /home/******/public_html/components/com_content/content.php:16
ContentController -> display() @ /home/*******/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php:730
JControllerLegacy -> display() @ /home/*******/public_html/components/com_content/controller.php:79
ContentViewArticle -> display() @ /home/******/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php:693
JError :: raiseWarning() @ /home/******/public_html/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php:52
JError :: raise() @ /home/******/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php:276
```

Answer (score 0):

please open your database phpmyadmin execute this SQL command.

TRUNCATE TABLE olrky_redirect_links;

and solved your problem

Comment: WARNING: This deletes all elements in the table. And does not help anyway.

Comment: i tested my web site problem resolved. this table olrky_redirect_links empty. if you need your table backup later test. if you living problem. your backup use

Comment: Try to explain in more detail what the problem is and why you need to clean the table etc. (and what is lost by doing this). If the user really wants to start over, he should not only clean this table but reset the database completely, or more errors with stale data will happen later.